# LARAVEL: Como validar un campo que debe ser una fecha posterior a la actual y no superar x cantidad de meses

Tags: laravel, date, validación, laravel-livewire, carbon

En laravel estoy haciendo un registro de inscripción en donde tengo que validar un campo de "fecha probable de parto"
Necesito que sea una fecha futura a la actual, en donde usé la regla after_or_equal:today, pero también necesito validar que sea una fecha que no supere los 9 meses en adelante a partir de la fecha actual.

`'fecha_probable_parto' => 'date | after_or_equal:today',`

Ademas tambien tengo que validar un campo de "fecha de diagnostico del embarazo" donde usé before_or_equal:today, pero tambien necesito que sea una fecha que no sea anterior a los 9 meses anteriores a la fecha actual.

`'fecha_diagnostico_embarazo' => 'date | before_or_equal:today',`

Que regla o reglas puedo usar? como las implemento a la hora de establecer mis validaciones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con los datos que proporcionas, creo que casi lo tienes. Yo lo usaría de la siguiente manera:

```
[
    'fecha_probable_parto' => ['required', 'date', 'after:today'],
    'fecha_diagnostico_embarazo' => ['required', 'date', 'before_or_equal:'.Carbon::now()->addMonths(9)->format('Y-m-d')]
]
```

Así la fecha de parto siempre va a ser después de hoy, pero antes o igual a la fecha que quieras antes de cumplir 9 meses.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mejor seria que uses un Rule Objects ya ahi colocas todas la lógica para esta validación.

Puede ver su implementación acá: [using-rule-objects](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#using-rule-objects)